# Wireless connection problem - 14.02.2 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless

I am a lay person when it comes to computers, but I want to give Ubuntu a try.  I recently installed Ubuntu and I am having trouble accessing WiFi.  It appears on the face to connect- enable WiFi is checked and the wireless signal icon appears-- but browsers won't load.

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` yields the following:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff1e]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0181]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
```

Comment: nm-tool is just listing the wired connection so can you edit to add the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to your question

Comment: Could you have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and post some additional information?